# Differently kinded ReaderT?

Tags: haskell, higher-kinded-types, data-kinds

At the risk of this becoming an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), is it possible to have a `ReaderT` with a differently kinded environment? I'm trying something like...

```
type AppM (perms :: [*]) = ReaderT (perms :: [*]) IO
```

...but the compiler complains with...

```
Expected a type, but ‘(perms :: [*])’ has kind ‘[*]’
```

...presumably because `ReaderT` is defined as...

```
newtype ReaderT r (m :: k -> *) (a :: k) = ReaderT {runReaderT :: r -> m a}
```

...where `r` is of kind `*`

I'm trying to track permissions/roles at a type-level, and my ultimate goal is to write functions like...

```
ensurePermission :: (p :: Permission) -> AppM (p :. ps) ()
```

... where every call to `ensurePermission` appends/prepends a new permission to the monad's permission list (at the type-level).

### Edit

I tried the following, and it seems to compile, but I'm not sure what's going on. Conceptually isn't `perms` still of kind `[*]`. How is this snippet acceptable to the compiler, but the original one isn't?

```
data HList (l :: [*]) where
  HNil :: HList '[]
  HCons :: e -> HList l -> HList (e ': l)

type AppM (perms :: [*]) = ReaderT (HList perms) IO
```

### Edit #2

I tried evolving my code snippet to further match my end-goal, but I'm stuck again with a different "kind" problem:

The compiler doesn't accept the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

data Permission = PermissionA
                | PermissionB

$(genSingletons [''Permission])

data PList (perms :: [Permission]) where
  PNil :: PList '[]
  PCons :: p -> PList perms -> PList (p ': perms)

--     • Expected kind ‘[Permission]’, but ‘p : perms’ has kind ‘[*]’
--     • In the first argument of ‘PList’, namely ‘(p : perms)’
--       In the type ‘PList (p : perms)’
--       In the definition of data constructor ‘PCons’
--    |
-- 26 |   PCons :: p -> PList perms -> PList (p ': perms)
--    |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Neither does it accept the following variation...

```
data PList (perms :: [Permission]) where
  PNil :: PList '[]
  PCons :: (p :: Permission) -> PList perms -> PList (p ': perms)


--     • Expected a type, but ‘(p :: Permission)’ has kind ‘Permission’
--     • In the type ‘(p :: Permission)’
--       In the definition of data constructor ‘PCons’
--       In the data declaration for ‘PList’
--    |
-- 26 |   PCons :: (p :: Permission) -> PList perms -> PList (p ': perms)
--    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Part of the issue is that the kind `[*]` does not have any types which have values. The type checker will reject your `ensurePermission` because of this. You can only have types of kind `*` (or `#`) in places where you have values, if that makes sense. You need something like a `Proxy`.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `type AppM (perms :: [*]) = ReaderT (Hlist perms) IO` instead? I.e., a reader accessing to a value for any type in the list-of-types?

Comment: @David I'm not sure I understand you completely. More so because I'm drawing inspiration from Servant's `Context` type and `HasContextEntry` type-class - https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.1/servant-server-0.14.1/Servant-Server.html#t:Context

Comment: @chi it could be that you're right. I'm assuming an `HList` is a heterogeneous list, right? Which (well-maintained) library provides this? I tried searching on stackage/hackage and found a lot of them. In fact Servant itself provides an `HList` type, but it is only for HTTP headers.

Comment: @chi i tried your suggestion, and it seems to compile. But I'm not sure why. I have edited the question.

Comment: Yes, that's a heterogeneous list. I was also confused by the many packages providing it -- I don't know what would be the right one to use.

Comment: In that way, `perms` still has kind `[*]` (list of types), but `HList :: [*] -> *` converts that into a plain type, so it can be used in the reader monad. The kind of `perms` does not matter, only the kind of the `ReaderT` argument does.

Comment: @chi I'm stuck with  a new problem. I tried "specialising" HList by renaming it to `PList (perms :: [Permission])`, but the compiler doesn't like what I've done. I've editing the question again.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda Types whose kinds are types lifted with `-XDataKinds` don't have values, they are purely type-level metadata. Types of kind `Type` (formerly known as `*`) do have values. `p` has kind `Permission`, not `Type`, and therefore can't have values. You could try to pass a `Proxy` parameterized by `p`. Proxies have a phantom type parameter that is poly-kinded. You could also try using `-XTypeApplications` to specify `p`, instead of an actual value.

Comment: @danidiaz Is there any way to introspect (using something like `:t`, `:i`, etc) and figure out which types have values, and which don't? Also, I don't understand why the compiler would be bothered with types that can have values and types that can't. I tried the following - `data EmptyType ; foo :: EmptyType -> () ; foo _ = ()` and it compiled. Is this happening because of `':`? Does that expect both the operands to be of kind `*` ? How do inspect the `':` operator in GHCi?

Comment: I'm really confused about the "laws / rules" of working with different kinds. Can I not write data-constructors using type of different kinds (i.e. not `*`)? Or is that the type-level operator `':` is of kind `* -> [*] -> *` and therefore cannot work on types of another kind.

Comment: @David it seems like I have hit the issue that you were referring to in your comment. If the compiler checks for which types can have values, or not, I don't understand why the following compiles - `data EmptyType ; foo :: EmptyType -> () ; foo _ = ()`

Comment: aaargh... why does the following compile! Where is all of this behaviour documented? `data PList (perms :: [Permission]) where
  PCons :: Proxy (p :: Permission) -> PList perms -> PList (p ': perms)
`

Comment: The example with `Proxy` compiles because the `Proxy` type has a value constructor, also named `Proxy`. The value is not used though, `Proxy` only serves as a roundabout way to pass type-level information. Notice that the kind of the `Proxy` type constructor is something like `forall {k}. k -> Type`. You give it a (phantom) type parameter of any kind, and it gives you a type of kind `Type` (also known as `*`) that can have values, namely the `Proxy` value.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda I worded that poorly (which I realized too long after I left the comment). Those are two separate things: 1) A kind such as `[*]` does not have types which contain values. 2) The compiler will not allow types of kind `[*]` (and similar) to occur at "value positions" (not sure what the exact phrase would be here, actually, so let me know if that isn't very clear). 2 is not fully because of 1, but they are both (separately) true.

Comment: Also, you could argue that your empty type *does* have values: the bottom value. And since types of kind `[*]` won't even compile in such a position, they *truly* don't have any values. But that isn't really exactly what the compiler checking for, when it rejects a type like `f :: ['a','b','c'] -> ()`.

Comment: @chi, `vinyl` is well maintained, and `HList` is basically `Rec Identity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a separate Gist, you commented:

> @K.A.Buhr, wow! Thank you for such a detailed reply. You are correct that this is an XY problem, and you've pretty-much nailed the actual problem that I'm trying to solve. Another important piece of context is that, at some point these type-level permissions will have to be "reified" at the value-level. This is because the final check is against the permissions granted to the currently signed-in user, which are stored in the DB.
>
> Taking this into account, I'm planning to have two "general" functions, say:
>
> ```
> requiredPermission :: (RequiredPermission p ps) => Proxy p -> AppM ps ()
> optionalPermission :: (OptionalPermission p ps) => Proxy p -> AppM ps ()
> ```
>
> Here's the difference:
>
> - `requiredPermission` will simply add the permission to the type-level list and it will be verified when `runAppM` is called. If the current user does not have ALL the required permissions, then `runAppM` will immediately throw a 401 error to the UI.
> - On the other hand, `optionalPermission` will extract the user from the `Reader` environment, check the permission, and return a True / False. `runAppM` will do nothing with `OptionalPermissions`. These will be for cases where the absence of a permission should NOT fail the entire action, but skip a specific step in the action.
>
> Given this context, I'm not sure if I would end-up with functions, like grantA or grantB. The "unwrapping" of ALL the RequestPermissions in the AppM constructor will be done by runAppM, which will also ensure that the currently sign-in user actually has these permissions.

Note that there's more than one way to "reify" types.  For example, the following program -- through devious black magic trickery -- manages to reify a runtime type without the use of proxies or singletons!

```
main = do
  putStr "Enter \"Int\" or \"String\": "
  s <- getLine
  putStrLn $ case s of "Int" ->    "Here is an integer: " ++ show (42 :: Int)
                       "String" -> "Here is a string: " ++ show ("hello" :: String)
```

Similarly, the following variant of `grantA` manages to lift user permissions known only at runtime to the type-level:

```
whenA :: M (PermissionA:ps) () -> M ps ()
whenA act = do
  perms <- asks userPermissions  -- get perms from environment
  if PermissionA `elem` perms
    then act
    else notAuthenticated
```

Singletons could be used here to avoid boilerplate for different permissions and to improve type safety in this trusted piece of code (i.e., so that the two occurrences of `PermissionA` are forced to match).  Similarly, constraint kinds might save 5 or 6 characters per permission check.  However, neither of these improvements is necessary, and they may add substantial complexity that should be avoided if at all possible until **after** you get a working prototype.  In other words, elegant code that doesn't work isn't all that elegant.

In that spirit, here is how I might adapt my original solution to support a set of "required" permissions that must be satisfied at specific "entry points" (e.g., specific routed web requests), and to perform runtime permission checking against a user database.

First, we have a set of permissions:

```
data Permission
  = ReadP            -- read content
  | MetaP            -- view (private) metadata
  | WriteP           -- write content
  | AdminP           -- all permissions
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

and a user databsae:

```
type User = String
userDB :: [(User, [Permission])]
userDB
  = [ ("alice", [ReadP, WriteP])
    , ("bob",   [ReadP])
    , ("carl",  [AdminP])
    ]
```

as well as an environment that includes user permissions and whatever else you want to carry around in a reader:

```
data Env = Env
  { uperms :: [Permission]   -- user's actual permissions
  , user :: String           -- other Env stuff
  } deriving (Show)
```

We'll also want functions at the type and term level to check permission lists:

```
type family Allowed (p :: Permission) ps where
  Allowed p (AdminP:ps) = True   -- admins can do anything
  Allowed p '[] = False
  Allowed p (p:ps) = True
  Allowed p (q:ps) = Allowed p ps
allowed :: Permission -> [Permission] -> Bool
allowed p (AdminP:ps) = True
allowed p (q:ps) | p == q = True
                 | otherwise = allowed p ps
allowed p [] = False
```

(Yes, you could use the `singletons` library to define both functions simultaneously, but let's do this without singletons for now.)

As before, we'll have a monad that carries around a list of permissions.  You can think of it as the list of permissions that have been checked and verified at this point in the code.  We'll make this a monad transformer for a general `m` with a `ReaderT Env` component:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
newtype AppT (perms :: [Permission]) m a = AppT (ReaderT Env m a)
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader Env, MonadIO)
```

Now, we can define actions in this monad that form the building blocks for our application:

```
readPage :: (Allowed ReadP perms ~ True, MonadIO m) => Int -> AppT perms m ()
readPage n = say $ "Read page " ++ show n

metaPage :: (Allowed ReadP perms ~ True, MonadIO m) => Int -> AppT perms m ()
metaPage n = say $ "Secret metadata " ++ show (n^2)

editPage :: (Allowed ReadP perms ~ True, Allowed WriteP perms ~ True, MonadIO m) => Int -> AppT perms m ()
editPage n = say $ "Edit page " ++ show n

say :: MonadIO m => String -> m ()
say = liftIO . putStrLn
```

In each case, the action is allowed in any context where the list of permissions that have been checked and verified includes the needed permissions listed in the type signature.  (Yes, constraint kinds would work fine here, but let's keep it simple.)

We can build more complicated actions out of these, as we did in my other answer:

```
readPageWithMeta :: ( Allowed 'ReadP perms ~ 'True, Allowed 'MetaP perms ~ 'True
    , MonadIO m) => Int -> AppT perms m ()
readPageWithMeta n = do
  readPage n
  metaPage n
```

Note that GHC can actually infer this type signature automatically, determining that `ReadP` and `MetaP` permissions are required.  If we wanted to make the `MetaP` permission optional, we could write:

```
readPageWithOptionalMeta :: ( Allowed 'ReadP perms ~ 'True
    , MonadIO m) => Int -> AppT perms m ()
readPageWithOptionalMeta n = do
  readPage n
  whenMeta $ metaPage n
```

where the `whenMeta` allows an optional action depending on available permissions.  (See below.)  Again, this signature can be inferred automatically.

So far, while we've allowed for optional permissions, we haven't explicitly dealt with "required" permissions.  Those are going to be specified at **entry points** which will be defined using a separate monad:

```
newtype EntryT' (reqP :: [Permission]) (checkedP :: [Permission]) m a
  = EntryT (ReaderT Env m a)
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader Env, MonadIO)
type EntryT reqP = EntryT' reqP reqP
```

This requires some explanation.  An `EntryT'` (with the tick mark) has two lists of permissions.  The first is the full list of required permissions for the entry point and has a fixed value for each particular entry point.  The second is the subset of those permissions that have been "checked" (in the static sense that a function call is in place to check and verify the user has the required permission).  It will be built up from the empty list to the full list of required permissions when we define entry points.  We'll use it as a type-level mechanism to ensure that the correct set of permission checking function calls is in place.  An `EntryT` (no tick) has its (statically) checked permissions equal to its required permissions, and that's how we know it's safe to run (against a particular user's dynamically determined set of permissions, which will all be checked as guaranteed by the type).

```
runEntryT :: MonadIO m => User -> EntryT req m () -> m ()
runEntryT u (EntryT act)
  = case lookup u userDB of
      Nothing   -> say $ "error 401: no such user '" ++ u ++ "'"
      Just perms -> runReaderT act (Env perms u)
```

To define an entry point, we'll use something like this:

```
entryReadPage :: MonadIO m => Int -> EntryT '[ReadP] m ()
entryReadPage n = _somethingspecial_ $ do
  readPage n
  whenMeta $ metaPage n
```

Note that we have a `do` block here built out of `AppT` building blocks.  In fact, it's equivalent to `readPageWithOptionalMeta` above and so has type:

```
(Allowed 'ReadP perms ~ 'True, MonadIO m) => Int -> AppT perms m ()
```

The `_somethingspecial_` here needs to adapt this `AppT` (whose list of permissions requires that `ReadP` be checked and verified before it is run) to an entry point whose lists of required and (statically) checked permissions is `[ReadP]`.  We'll do this using a set of functions to check actual runtime permissions:

```
requireRead :: MonadIO m => EntryT' r c m () -> EntryT' r (ReadP:c) m ()
requireRead = unsafeRequire ReadP
requireWrite :: MonadIO m => EntryT' r c m () -> EntryT' r (WriteP:c) m ()
requireWrite = unsafeRequire WriteP
-- plus functions for the rest of the permissions
```

all defined in terms of:

```
unsafeRequire :: MonadIO m => Permission -> EntryT' r c m () -> EntryT' r c' m ()
unsafeRequire p act = do
  ps <- asks uperms
  if allowed p ps
    then coerce act
    else say $ "error 403: requires permission " ++ show p
```

Now, when we write:

```
entryReadPage :: MonadIO m => Int -> EntryT '[ReadP] m ()
entryReadPage n = requireRead . _ $ do
  readPage n
  whenMeta $ metaPage n
```

the outer type is correct, reflecting the fact that the list of `requireXXX` functions matches the list of required permissions in the type signature.  The remaining hole has type:

```
AppT perms0 m0 () -> EntryT' '[ReadP] '[] m ()
```

Because of the way we've structured our permission checking, this is a special case of the safe transformation:

```
toRunAppT :: MonadIO m => AppT r m a -> EntryT' r '[] m a
toRunAppT = coerce
```

In other words, we can write our final entry point definition using a fairly nice syntax which literally says that we "require `Read` to run this `AppT`":

```
entryReadPage :: MonadIO m => Int -> EntryT '[ReadP] m ()
entryReadPage n = requireRead . toRunAppT $ do
  readPage n
  whenMeta $ metaPage n
```

and similarly:

```
entryEditPage :: MonadIO m => Int -> EntryT '[ReadP, WriteP] m ()
entryEditPage n = requireRead . requireWrite . toRunAppT $ do
  editPage n
  whenMeta $ metaPage n
```

Observe that the list of required permissions is included explicitly in the entry point's type, and the composed list of `requireXXX` functions that perform runtime checking of those permissions must exactly match those same permissions, in the same order, for it to type check.

The last piece of the puzzle is the implementation of `whenMeta`, which performs a runtime permission check and executes an optional action if the permission is available.

```
whenMeta :: Monad m => AppT (MetaP:perms) m () -> AppT perms m ()
whenMeta = unsafeWhen MetaP
-- and similar functions for other permissions

unsafeWhen :: Monad m => Permission -> AppT perms m () -> AppT perms' m ()
unsafeWhen p act = do
  ps <- asks uperms
  if allowed p ps
    then coerce act
    else return ()
```

Here's the full program with a test harnass.  You can see that:

```
Username/Req (e.g., "alice Read 5"): alice Read 5    -- Alice...
Read page 5
Username/Req (e.g., "alice Read 5"): bob Read 5      -- and Bob can read.
Read page 5
Username/Req (e.g., "alice Read 5"): carl Read 5     -- Carl gets the metadata, too
Read page 5
Secret metadata 25
Username/Req (e.g., "alice Read 5"): bob Edit 3      -- Bob can't edit...
error 403: requires permission WriteP
Username/Req (e.g., "alice Read 5"): alice Edit 3    -- but Alice can.
Edit page 3
Username/Req (e.g., "alice Read 5"):
```

The source:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

module Realistic where

import Control.Monad.Reader
import Data.Coerce

-- |Set of permissions
data Permission
  = ReadP            -- read content
  | MetaP            -- view (private) metadata
  | WriteP           -- write content
  | AdminP           -- all permissions
  deriving (Show, Eq)

type User = String
-- |User database
userDB :: [(User, [Permission])]
userDB
  = [ ("alice", [ReadP, WriteP])
    , ("bob",   [ReadP])
    , ("carl",  [AdminP])
    ]

-- |Environment with 'uperms' and whatever else is needed
data Env = Env
  { uperms :: [Permission]   -- user's actual permissions
  , user :: String           -- other Env stuff
  } deriving (Show)

-- |Check for permission in type-level and term-level lists
type family Allowed (p :: Permission) ps where
  Allowed p (AdminP:ps) = True   -- admins can do anything
  Allowed p '[] = False
  Allowed p (p:ps) = True
  Allowed p (q:ps) = Allowed p ps
allowed :: Permission -> [Permission] -> Bool
allowed p (AdminP:ps) = True
allowed p (q:ps) | p == q = True
                 | otherwise = allowed p ps
allowed p [] = False

-- |An application action running with a given list of checked permissions.
newtype AppT (perms :: [Permission]) m a = AppT (ReaderT Env m a)
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader Env, MonadIO)

-- Optional actions run if permissions are available at runtime.
whenRead :: Monad m => AppT (ReadP:perms) m () -> AppT perms m ()
whenRead = unsafeWhen ReadP
whenMeta :: Monad m => AppT (MetaP:perms) m () -> AppT perms m ()
whenMeta = unsafeWhen MetaP
whenWrite :: Monad m => AppT (WriteP:perms) m () -> AppT perms m ()
whenWrite = unsafeWhen WriteP
whenAdmin :: Monad m => AppT (AdminP:perms) m () -> AppT perms m ()
whenAdmin = unsafeWhen AdminP
unsafeWhen :: Monad m => Permission -> AppT perms m () -> AppT perms' m ()
unsafeWhen p act = do
  ps <- asks uperms
  if allowed p ps
    then coerce act
    else return ()

-- |An entry point, requiring a list of permissions
newtype EntryT' (reqP :: [Permission]) (checkedP :: [Permission]) m a
  = EntryT (ReaderT Env m a)
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader Env, MonadIO)
-- |An entry point whose full list of required permission has been (statically) checked).
type EntryT reqP = EntryT' reqP reqP

-- |Run an entry point whose required permissions have been checked.
runEntryT :: MonadIO m => User -> EntryT req m () -> m ()
runEntryT u (EntryT act)
  = case lookup u userDB of
      Nothing   -> say $ "error 401: no such user '" ++ u ++ "'"
      Just perms -> runReaderT act (Env perms u)

-- Functions to build the list of required permissions for an entry point.
requireRead :: MonadIO m => EntryT' r c m () -> EntryT' r (ReadP:c) m ()
requireRead = unsafeRequire ReadP
requireMeta :: MonadIO m => EntryT' r c m () -> EntryT' r (MetaP:c) m ()
requireMeta = unsafeRequire MetaP
requireWrite :: MonadIO m => EntryT' r c m () -> EntryT' r (WriteP:c) m ()
requireWrite = unsafeRequire WriteP
requireAdmin :: MonadIO m => EntryT' r c m () -> EntryT' r (AdminP:c) m ()
requireAdmin = unsafeRequire AdminP
unsafeRequire :: MonadIO m => Permission -> EntryT' r c m () -> EntryT' r c' m ()
unsafeRequire p act = do
  ps <- asks uperms
  if allowed p ps
    then coerce act
    else say $ "error 403: requires permission " ++ show p

-- Adapt an entry point w/ all static checks to an underlying application action.
toRunAppT :: MonadIO m => AppT r m a -> EntryT' r '[] m a
toRunAppT = coerce

-- Example application actions
readPage :: (Allowed ReadP perms ~ True, MonadIO m) => Int -> AppT perms m ()
readPage n = say $ "Read page " ++ show n
metaPage :: (Allowed ReadP perms ~ True, MonadIO m) => Int -> AppT perms m ()
metaPage n = say $ "Secret metadata " ++ show (n^2)
editPage :: (Allowed ReadP perms ~ True, Allowed WriteP perms ~ True, MonadIO m) => Int -> AppT perms m ()
editPage n = say $ "Edit page " ++ show n

say :: MonadIO m => String -> m ()
say = liftIO . putStrLn

-- Example entry points
entryReadPage :: MonadIO m => Int -> EntryT '[ReadP] m ()
entryReadPage n = requireRead . toRunAppT $ do
  readPage n
  whenMeta $ metaPage n
entryEditPage :: MonadIO m => Int -> EntryT '[ReadP, WriteP] m ()
entryEditPage n = requireRead . requireWrite . toRunAppT $ do
  editPage n
  whenMeta $ metaPage n

-- Test harnass
data Req = Read Int
         | Edit Int
         deriving (Read)
main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStr "Username/Req (e.g., \"alice Read 5\"): "
  ln <- getLine
  case break (==' ') ln of
    (user, ' ':rest) -> case read rest of
      Read n -> runEntryT user $ entryReadPage n
      Edit n -> runEntryT user $ entryEditPage n
  main
```

Comment: Thank you for a mini blog-post again :) I'll try to fiddle with your code examples when I'm on my laptop, but the first thing that jumps out is the need for explicitly converting an `(Allowed p perms) => AppT pems m`  into a more concrete form, using the mechanical `requireX . toRunAppT` transformation. Is there no way to use the constraints on `AppT perms m` to concretise the monad automatically? The type-level list that `requiredX` is building , can it not be built when a call to `readPage / writePage` is being made. Btw , this is how I went down the original ReaderT / HList rabbit hole.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I intentionally avoided it because it's a bad design.  You *think* you want required permissions to bubble up to entry points and then be checked in some opaque manner at the top level, but then (1) you make it easier for code changes in the guts of the app to lock users out of entry points at runtime; and (2) you lose the explicit app security specification provided by the entry point signatures.

Comment: I spent a lot of time fiddling around with code to understand the downsides of having a general/single function to do permission checking, but wasn't able to figure it out. Could you please elaborate your comment: `(1) you make it easier for code changes in the guts of the app to lock users out of entry points at runtime; and (2) you lose the explicit app security specification provided by the entry point signatures.`

Comment: (1) If you refactor low-level code used by multiple entry points, it's easy to introduce a new permission requirement by accident.  If permissions percolate up, there's no type error, but suddenly visiting the home page requires `CommentEditP`.  (2) Related to (1), the entry point type signatures provide a documented specification for the security guarantees of your app.  What permissions are needed to run `entryX`?  Check the signature.  Code changes require spec changes?  A human being, not a compiler, should be overseeing those changes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - it makes sense to me now. Btw, I've taken tips from your solution and tried a PoC for my app at https://gist.github.com/saurabhnanda/b783c4a99d56c527613cf6cb3febce4c#file-appm-hs - Right now it is for certain feature-flags that are enabled on a per-customer basis, instead of permissions. I have a polymorphic `requireFeature` function that can introduce a type-level constraint for any feature-flag that is passed to it. Similarly, there is a polymorphic `runAction` that needs you to pass a list of feature-flags as a proxy (contd..)

Comment: (cont..) Since one is forced to call `runAction` with an **explicit** list of feature-flags, it protects programmers from refactoring and messing up the feature-flags (or, in the future, permission lists). Do you foresee any problems with this "simplified" approach?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I think we have an XY problem here, so let's take a step back.

A `Reader` is a monad for carrying around a **value** that can be conveniently read.  You don't have a value -- you have a list of permissions you want to enforce at type level -- so I don't think you need or want a reader, or a heterogeneous list, or anything else like that.

Instead, given a list of boolean permissions:

```
data Permission = PermissionA | PermissionB deriving (Show)
```

you want to define a monad parametrized at the type level with the list of its granted permissions.  A newtype wrapper around your underlying `IO` monad will do:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
newtype M (ps :: [Permission]) a = M (IO a) deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)
```

You'll also want a type function (AKA type family) to determine if a permission is in a permission list:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, TypeOperators #-}
type family Allowed (p :: Permission) ps where
  Allowed p '[] = False
  Allowed p (p:ps) = True
  Allowed p (q:ps) = Allowed p ps
```

Now, if you want to write functions that require certain permissions, you write things like:

```
deleteA :: (Allowed PermissionA ps ~ True) => M ps ()
deleteA = M $ print "Deleted A"

readB :: (Allowed PermissionB ps ~ True) => M ps ()
readB = M $ print "Read B"

copyBtoA :: ( Allowed PermissionA ps ~ True
            , Allowed PermissionB ps ~ True) => M ps ()
copyBtoA = M $ print "Copied B to A"
```

To run an `M` action, we introduce a function that runs one with no permissions:

```
-- runM with no permissions
runM :: M '[] a -> IO a
runM (M act) = act
```

Note that if you try `runM readB`, you'll get a type error (couldn't match `False` with `True` -- not the greatest error message, but...).

To grant permissions, we introduce the functions:

```
-- grant permissions
grantA :: M (PermissionA:ps) a -> M ps a
grantA (M act) = M act
grantB :: M (PermissionB:ps) a -> M ps a
grantB (M act) = M act
```

These functions are essentially identity functions at the term level -- they just unwrap and rewrap the `M` constructor.  However, their operation at the type level is to add a permission to their input argument.  This means that:

```
runM $ grantB $ readB
```

now type-checks.  So do:

```
runM $ grantA . grantB $ readB
runM $ grantB . grantA $ readB
runM $ grantB . grantA . grantB $ readB
etc.
```

Then you can write programs like:

```
program :: IO ()
program = runM $ do
  grantA $ do
    deleteA
    grantB $ do
      readB
      copyBtoA
```

while rejecting programs like:

```
program1 :: IO ()
program1 = runM $ do
  grantA $ do
    deleteA
    grantB $ do
      readB
    copyBtoA    -- error, needs PermissionB
```

This infrastructure is maybe a little ugly, but it should be all you need for type-based, fully compile-time permission checking.

Maybe try this version out for a bit and see if it meets your needs.  The full code is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving,
             TypeFamilies, TypeOperators #-}

data Permission = PermissionA | PermissionB deriving (Show)

newtype M (ps :: [Permission]) a = M (IO a) deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

type family Allowed (p :: Permission) ps where
  Allowed p '[] = False
  Allowed p (p:ps) = True
  Allowed p (q:ps) = Allowed p ps

-- runM with no permissions
runM :: M '[] a -> IO a
runM (M act) = act

-- grant permissions
grantA :: M (PermissionA:ps) a -> M ps a
grantA (M act) = M act
grantB :: M (PermissionB:ps) a -> M ps a
grantB (M act) = M act

deleteA :: (Allowed PermissionA ps ~ True) => M ps ()
deleteA = M $ print "Deleted A"

readB :: (Allowed PermissionB ps ~ True) => M ps ()
readB = M $ print "Read B"

copyBtoA :: ( Allowed PermissionA ps ~ True
            , Allowed PermissionB ps ~ True) => M ps ()
copyBtoA = M $ print "Copied B to A"

program :: IO ()
program = runM $ do
  grantA $ do
    deleteA
    grantB $ do
      readB
      copyBtoA
```

Two additional notes based on @dfeuer's comment.  First, it reminded me that `grantA` and `grantB` could equally well be written using the "safe" `coerce` function from `Data.Coerce` as follows.  There's no difference in the code generated between this version and the version above, so it's a matter of taste:

```
import Data.Coerce

-- grant permissions
grantA :: M (PermissionA:ps) a -> M ps a
grantA = coerce
grantB :: M (PermissionB:ps) a -> M ps a
grantB = coerce
```

Second, what @dfeuer is talking about is that there's no clear separation here between a base of trusted code for controlling permissions and the "rest" of the code that relies on the type system to enforce the permission system.  For example, pattern matching on the `M` constructor is inherently dangerous, since you can extract an `IO a` from one permission context and reconstruct it in another.  (This is basically what `grantA` and `grantB` are doing to elevate privileges unconditionally.)  If you do this "by accident" outside of the trusted code base, you might end up bypassing the permission system.  In many applications, this isn't a big deal.

However, if you were trying to prove a system secure, you might want a small trusted code base that works with the dangerous `M` constructor and exports only a "safe" API that ensures security through the type system.  In that case, you'd have a module that exports the type `M`, but not its constructor `M(..)`.  Instead, you'd export smart constructors for creating `M` actions with appropriate permissions.

Also, for obscure technical reasons, even without exporting the `M` constructor, it would still be possible for "untrusted" code to coerce between different permission contexts:

```
stealPermission :: M (PermissionA:ps) a -> M ps a
stealPermission = coerce
```

because the first parameter to the `M` type constructor has a so-called "role" that defaults to "phantom" instead of "nominal".  If you override this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RoleAnnotations #-}
type role M nominal _
```

then `coerce` can only be used where the constructor is in scope, which closes this loophole.  Untrusted code could still use `unsafeCoerce`, but there are mechanisms (Google for "Safe Haskell") to prevent this.

Comment: There should be a role annotation to protect the phantom, and the newtype constructor shouldn't be exported.

Comment: Okay, I've added a note at the end that I think address this.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr, wow! Thank you for such a detailed reply. You are correct that this is an XY problem, and you've pretty-much nailed the actual problem that I'm trying to solve. I ended up writing a very long reply which crossed StackOverflow's comment limit. Please see if you can read https://gist.github.com/saurabhnanda/b783c4a99d56c527613cf6cb3febce4c

Comment: @K.A.Buhr do I need to enable `AllowAmbiguousTypes` to be able to write functions like `readA` and `deleteB`. I tried something like https://gist.github.com/saurabhnanda/b783c4a99d56c527613cf6cb3febce4c#file-try2-hs and the compiler is ending up with ambiguous type-variables.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr is there any way to make this technique work with a completely polymorphic monad `m`? To enable testing, all our code is polymorphic in `m` and is concretised only by the `runAppM` function. I tried writing a ConstraintKind that looks like `type (HasApp p m) = (RequiredPermission p ps ~ True, m ps)`, but it didn't work due to `Not in scope: type variable ‘ps’`

Comment: @K.A.Buhr I tried enabling `AllowAmbiguousTypes`, but it seems that the compiler still gets confused at the call-site of `requiredPermission` - https://gist.github.com/saurabhnanda/b783c4a99d56c527613cf6cb3febce4c#file-requiredpermission-hs

Comment: @K.A.Buhr I tried fiddling with the your code, and the the problem surfaces there as well. It seems that one cannot use `deleteA` / `readB` in isolation. They **have** to be used in conjunction with `grantA`/`grantB` for the code to type-check.

Comment: Minor note: as a convenience, you can make `type family Allowed' (p :: Permission) (ps :: [Permission]) :: Bool` and then a type alias `type Allowed p ps = Allowed' p ps ~ 'True` with `ConstraintKinds`, then you don’t need the `~ 'True` at the use sites

Comment: I think many of these would need to be asked as additional SO questions (and you probably have a half dozen SO-sized questions you've posed here).  However, see my other answer, too.