# Unable to convert type-level list back to value-level using singletons library

Tags: haskell, singleton, data-kinds

I'm trying to write s *reasonably* statically-checked authorisation system [1], and currently struggling with trying to write a function that will extract the required permissions from a type-level annotation/phantom to the value-level.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Try5 where

import Control.Monad.Reader
import Data.Singletons
import Data.Singletons.TH


data Permission = PermA
                | PermB
                deriving (Eq, Show)
$(genSingletons [''Permission])

data Env = Env

newtype AppM (perms :: [Permission]) a = AppM (ReaderT Env IO a) deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO, MonadReader Env)

-- other functions for constructing an action in `AppM perms`
-- have been removed for brevity

runAction :: AppM (perms :: [Permission]) () -> IO ()
runAction _ = do
  let permissions :: [Permission] = fromSing $ singByProxy (Proxy :: Proxy (perms :: [Permission]))
  putStrLn $ "Huzzah, I freed the permissions from the type-level cage: " <> (show permissions)
  pure ()
```

#### Error:

```
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘singByProxy’
      prevents the constraint ‘(SingI a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance forall a (n1 :: a) (n2 :: [a]).
                 (SingI n1, SingI n2) =>
                 SingI (n1 : n2)
          -- Defined in ‘singletons-2.4.1:Data.Singletons.Prelude.Instances’
        instance SingI '[]
          -- Defined in ‘singletons-2.4.1:Data.Singletons.Prelude.Instances’
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘singByProxy (Proxy :: Proxy (perms :: [Permission]))’
      In the expression:
        fromSing $ singByProxy (Proxy :: Proxy (perms :: [Permission]))
      In a pattern binding:
        permissions :: [Permission]
          = fromSing $ singByProxy (Proxy :: Proxy (perms :: [Permission]))
   |
24 |   let permissions :: [Permission] = fromSing $ singByProxy (Proxy :: Proxy (perms :: [Permission]))
   |                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[1] More context can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56828016/534481

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`perms` is not in scope in the body of `runAction`. It needs to be explicitly bound with `forall`. See the [doc on `ScopedTypeVariables`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#lexically-scoped-type-variables).

Another problem is that to "demote" a value from types requires a `SingI` instance.

The key intuition is that `forall` introduces run-time irrelevant variables: if `runAction :: forall p. ...` doesn't have any constraints, `runAction @p` cannot actually depend on the value of `p`, it must always do the same thing. Richard Eisenberg's thesis, [*Dependent types in Haskell: Theory and Practice*](https://cs.brynmawr.edu/~rae/papers/2016/thesis/eisenberg-thesis.pdf), has more details about this matter (Section 4.2).

Thus the type of `runAction` should be something like this:

```
runAction :: forall perms. SingI perms => AppM perms () -> IO ()
```

Comment: Also note that, with this corrected signature, you can just write `let permissions = fromSing (sing :: SList perms)` using `SList` from `Data.Singletons.Prelude.List`.

Comment: Or even just `fromSing (sing :: Sing perms)`.  The point is that you don't need the separate proxy.

Comment: What's the intuition for `SingI x` constraint? A type (or kind?) which has singletons defined for it?

Comment: Also, why does `sing :: Sing perms` work, but `sing @perms` doesn't? On the other hand, it seems to work in a code snippet that looks like https://gist.github.com/saurabhnanda/20df208f9dd89c1f21f931e42952d79a#gistcomment-2955388

Comment: A constraint is an implicit argument (with a coherence property: there are no two values of the same type that can be passed in this way). From that point of view, `SingI x` is a `Sing x` value (which you get access to via `sing`).  
Try `sing @_ @perms`. `sing` is polykinded. i.e., `perms` could be any kind, and type applications makes that kind explicit as an argument (I believe there are proposals to change that quirk).